# Generalize Coroutine suspension type

Tags: haskell, types, coroutine

I am trying things out and have a coroutine which is going to request all `IO` actions from the outside. Therefore I have my custom suspension type `IORequest`. The problem is that for every kind of return type I need to add an extra constructor to `IORequest`.

Here is a working example (which requires [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) and [monad-coroutine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine))

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Coroutine

main :: IO ()
main = loop coroutine initialState

initialState :: Int
initialState = 65432

data IORequest x
  = RunIO (IO ()) (() -> x)
  | GetString (IO String) (String -> x)
  deriving Functor

request :: Monad m => IO () -> Coroutine IORequest m ()
request x = suspend (RunIO x return)

requestString :: Monad m => IO String -> Coroutine IORequest m String
requestString x = suspend (GetString x return)

coroutine :: Coroutine IORequest (State Int) Int
coroutine = do
  str <- requestString (readFile "my.txt")
  request (print "hello")
  return 5

loop :: Coroutine IORequest (State Int) Int -> Int -> IO ()
loop routine state =
  do let (request, state') = runState (resume routine) state
     case request of
       Left (GetString cmd q') -> do
         str <- cmd
         loop (q' str) state'
       Left (RunIO cmd q') -> do
         cmd
         loop (q' ()) state'
       Right result -> do
         print result
```

As you can see if at some point I need to run action `IO Bool` I will need to extend my `IORequest` and provide another helper method to be able to successfully use it (and also extending the pattern match in `loop`).

The question: can the `IORequest` be generalised somehow to allow general `(IO a) -> a` transition?

Something like

```
data IORequest x
  = forall a. RunIO (IO a) (a -> x)
```

(I wasn't able to make it work though, as `a` would escape when we try running it in `str <- cmd` for example)

Comment: Is it really necessary to put IO into the functor, rather than using it as the 'base monad' of `Coroutine f m` ? Intuitively that's where it belongs.

Comment: If I delete the appearances of IO in `IORequest`, I can write `requestString m = lift m >>= \x -> suspend (GetString x return)` with essentially the same type, `requestString  :: Monad m => m String -> Coroutine IORequest m String`

Comment: I'm not having trouble with the existential type, http://lpaste.net/1570704776058896384 . Of course it's equivalent to `newtype IORequest x = IORequest {runIORequest :: IO x}`, no?

Comment: It's just an experiment. I thought about separating pure code from IO. Let's say this coroutine is huge, and it needs to do some IO calls from time to time. I don't know if it will do any good, will ghc be able to do better optimisations to this coroutine in its current form or will the code that entirely runs in IO do better? I have no idea and would like to find out, to experiment.

Comment: Right, I'm not opposing it, just making points. I think that if you are using something like this type it is likely to be better to use IO at the bottom, rather than Identity; you are already paying for the complexity, so to speak. Coroutine does have an instance for MonadIO. But a suspension alternative  like `ReadFile FilePath (Text -> x)` would go better with the spirit of the library I think.

Comment: I also got this example working with the existential type, but my main code doesn't work. I would need to update this example a bit (which I'm not able to do at this moment)

Comment: Oddly `monad-coroutine` and FreeT don't have [distribute](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:distribute) but the state handling will be much simpler if it is done separately this way and not crammed into `loop`, your interpreter. Of course you can also write a `loop :: MonadIO m => Coroutine IORequest m r -> m r`, and then emerge with `StateT IO r` which you run the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about changing the data type to contain an existential quantifier seems perfectly reasonable. Most of your functions do not change.

```
data IORequest x = forall a . RunIO (IO a) (a -> x)

instance Functor IORequest where 
  fmap f (RunIO x g) = RunIO x (f.g)
```

Replace the other constructors with `RunIO`:

```
request :: Monad m => IO () -> Coroutine IORequest m ()
request x = suspend (RunIO x return)

requestString :: Monad m => IO String -> Coroutine IORequest m String
requestString x = suspend (RunIO x return)
```

And your loop function doesn't really change either - you just need to *not* ignore the value inside of `RunIO`:

```
loop :: Coroutine IORequest (State Int) Int -> Int -> IO ()
loop routine state =
  do let (request, state') = runState (resume routine) state
     case request of
       Left (RunIO cmd q') -> do
         a <- cmd
         loop (q' a) state'
       Right result -> do
         print result
```

Note that your `IORequest` can also be defined thus (if you have a fairly recent GHC):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Functor.Kan.Lan (Lan(..)) 
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))

type IORequest = Lan Identity IO 

pattern RunIO :: IO a -> (a -> x) -> IORequest x 
pattern RunIO x f <- Lan ((.Identity) -> f) x 
  where RunIO x f = Lan (f.runIdentity) x
```

Then it is clear to see that `IORequest` is now just isomorphic to `IO`. This follows from the laws of the left kan extension (namely, that `lanToComposedAdjoint` and `composedAdjointToLan` are witness to an isomorphism) but can be written directly:

```
actuallyJustIO_1 :: IORequest a -> IO a 
actuallyJustIO_1 = fmap runIdentity . lanToComposedAdjoint 

actuallyJustIO_2 :: IO a -> IORequest a 
actuallyJustIO_2 = composedAdjointToLan . fmap Identity
```

These two functions are clearly each others' left and right inverse, witnessing the isomorphism between `IORequest` and `IO`.